# Help optimize an Oracle query?

Tags: oracle, optimization

I'm trying to get better performance out of this Oracle query (which is terribly slow). I'm an Oracle beginner so maybe someone can point out a better way to approach this query.

I have a table with information on different families. I want to extract the different relationships based on a relationship type. The solution I came up with uses a hash join to query the database...

```
select *
from (
  with target_person as (
    select 
      p.person_id,
      p.family_number,
      p.relationship_type_id
    from 
      people p
    where
      p.relationship_type_id = 1 -- parent
  )
  select
    target_person.person_id,
    related_person.related_person_id,
    related_person.relationship_type_id
  from
    target_person,
    people related_person
  where
    target_person.person_id != related_person.person_id
    and target_person.family_number = related_person.family_number
    and related_person.relationship_type_id = 1
);
```

Comment: For a specific query it would be helpful if you could provide a link to somewhere to download a couple of table creates scripts and a little test data - that's the way I'd verify any solution I'd propose. Glad you got an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You realize this is equivalent to this?:

```
select *
from (
  with target_person as (
    select 
      p.person_id,
      p.family_number,
      p.relationship_type_id
    from 
      people p
    where
      p.relationship_type_id = 1 -- parent
  )
  select
    target_person.person_id,
    related_person.related_person_id,
    related_person.relationship_type_id
  from
    target_person,
    target_person related_person
  where
    target_person.person_id != related_person.person_id
    and target_person.family_number = related_person.family_number
);
```

So it's really as simple as this:

```
SELECT *
FROM people AS l
INNER JOIN people AS r
ON l.family_number = r.family_number
    AND l.relationship_type_id = 1
    AND r.relationship_type_id = 1
    AND l.person_id <> r.person_id
```

I would think the way to get this to go fastest is to have an index on `relationship_type_id`, `family_number`, `person_id` on your people table.

Comment: Yep, you're absolutely right. I was over-complicating the query. :)

Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

To help you with tuning can you post the following information:

1) For the tables involved, their table definition and index definitions on the tables.
2) A basic run down of the approximate number of rows in each of the table 
3) An explain plan of the query.  to get an explain plan: 
  a) run in sqlplus 
     explain plan SET STATEMENT_ID= for < insert your query>;
  b) run in sqlplus 
     select * from table(dbms_xplan.display('PLAN_TABLE',''));

With an explain plan and table/index info we can help you tune the query better.  With just the query we really don't have much to go by.  If you can provide a tkprof of the query execution, that would be of additional help as well.